# Are Queries Acceptable in Rails 3 Views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

My understanding of MVC is that SQL (or any persistence related) queries should only be performed in Model/Controller objects.  Accordingly, the [Rails 3 documentation about Controllers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#what-does-a-controller-do) states that:

> [Controllers] make the model data available to the view so it can display that data to the user.

However, the documentation also has examples of using [queries directly in View (HTML helper) code](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select):

```ruby
select("post", "person_id", Person.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] })
# Note the model query -----^
```

In Rails 3, is it generally acceptable to perform queries in Views or is there a compelling reason to strictly delegate such queries to Model or Controller objects?  Is the documentation just being demonstrative or is it exemplifying a best-practice?

Answer (score 6):

I think it's just demonstrative and it's not a good example to follow in general. It's close enough to SQL Spaghettis code that we can find in PHP.

I am reading the [Rails anti-patterns book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321604814) at the moment and they suggest scoping all those queries inside the models. The controllers will then have access to the methods defined in the models exposing the results to the views.

However if you don't pay attention you can quickly find yourselves having fat models and in order to avoid that you can use [Named scopes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/108-named-scope) which are of great help for this kind of patterns. The other key rule to pay attention to, is the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) which applied to Rails means that one model should not know too much about other model's implementation details. So if there is a query related to an associated model you should scope in this associated model.

Finally, the following [article](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model) (written by Jamis Buck) (*Skinny Controller, Fat Model*) is a good read on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

It is not generally acceptable to perform queries in Views, even if they are really simple. To avoid making heavy the controller, a good practice (as the documentation says) is create a Helper and put the query there.

Of course if you want reuse the query, is better to put it in the model, maybe using scopes.

Comment: But aren't helpers used mainly (exclusively?) in Views?  If we put a query in a helper then isn't it the same as doing a query in a View?

Comment: I see, my point of view was avoid to put it directly in the view, and justify the documentations. I use to extract simple data, often from a single table, a.i. an helper that create a combo box containing a list of items.